# Regex conversion on bbcode

Tags: regex, bbcode

We are moving from phpbb to a simpler system and some of the bbcode needs converting, particularly the "quote" code.  The current phpbb based quote code looks like this:

```
[quote="username":nw4lek0o]The quoted text[/quote:nw4lek0o]
```

and it needs to be simplified to this:

```
[quote=username]The quoted text[/quote]
```

So, basically two things: strip the double quotes from around the username, and strip the ID string from the opening and closing tag.

I'm not good at Regex. Help?

Comment: _suck at regex_ shouldn't be an excuse for _do it for me_ or _give me the code_.

Comment: @aelor Your edit _significantly_ changed the question.  You might have rather said: _I don't know regex._  You seem to be encouraging OP to ask for code with your edit.

Comment: @devnull the way OP had asked it originally was sounding the same. I just made it more clear so that people can flag it without any doubt in their minds

Comment: If you can fetch the username into a variable in the previous statement then, you can replace `:username` with blank and then quotes with blank. This can be a safer solution.

Comment: I'm not aware of bbcode stuff. But, I understand that the username is an user input. Regex on user input might go wrong anytime. You never know what the user enters. what if username has `:` or `]` ;)...Bad user but can happen.

Comment: Thank you to those who were willing to help someone who has only had to use regex occasionally and has to relearn it every time.  And particularly thanks for links to regex101.com, which I didn't know about.  That is an amazing tool that should help me significantly.  I will try the two answers below tonight and let you know the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
\[quote="(.+?)":.+?\](.+?)\[/quote:.+?]
```

And replace it with:

```
[quote=$1]$2[/quote]
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jL3xU2

Comment: This one is doing exactly what I asked for, except that I am finding newlines in the quoted text that I didn't expect.  I have tried to find a place where I could insert /s to include newlines, but it is not effective.  Suggestions?

Comment: So, you want new lines to be captured?

Comment: Yes, I want new lines captured.  As an alternative, if that's difficult, newlines could be converted into spaces.

Comment: @RobBrandt, use this `\[quote="(.+?)":.+?\]((.|\s)+?)\[/quote:.+?]`

Answer (score 0):

find `(?=\").|(?::\w+)` replace with blank.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/oN8fS2